# how to work in selenium with testNG in Netbeans IDE?

Tags: automation, testng

I am new in automation testing. I know that how to configure testNG with eclipse IDE but I did not get that how to configure testNG with netbeans IDE.

I have already included selenium webdriver library files in netbeans.

can anyone help me?

Thanks
Rohit Joshi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Download latest version of NetBeans
2. Download the TestNG plugin for NetBeans
3. If you are going to use Maven then get the TestNG Maven plugin for NetBeans
4. Start NetBeans IDE and go to Tools -> Plugins

NetBeans IDE

5. Go to Downloaded tab and select Add Plugins
6. Navigate to the location on your hard disk where you have saved the .nbm file and select it and click Open
7. The plugin is made visible in the Downloaded window
8. Select it and Install

There it is!! You are now privileged to use TestNG with your NetBeans.

To use TestNG, right click anywhere in the editor window and you can see TestNG. Mouse over it and create Test using TestNG.

You can also visit the following link https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/testng-screencast.html