# TestNG No runnable methods

Tags: java, selenium, testng

I have a problem with selenium and testNG, this is my code:

```
public class NewTestNGTest {

    @BeforeClass
    public void setUp() {
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

        driver.get("https://www.google.com");
    }

    @Test
    public void aTest() {
        System.out.println("Test");
    }

    @AfterClass
    public void cleanUp() {
        // code that will be invoked after this test ends
    }

}
```

and the error log shows:

> Testcase: initializationError(NewTestNGTest): Caused an ERROR
>   No runnable methods
>   java.lang.Exception: No runnable methods at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)

Any suggestions for me?

Thank you

Comment: Just to be sure.Your @Test refers to  import org.testng.annotations.Test  ? and you run the test with the command provided by TestNG plugin from your netbeans IDE ?

Comment: 1. Post the full source code. 2. Change `@BeforeClass` to `@Before`. 3. Change `@AfterClass` to `@After`. 3. Consider changing `aTest` to `testMyTestShouldDoThis`

Answer (score 0):

Please check if TestNG library is properly referenced in your eclipse project.

By default eclipse comes with JUnit bundled with it. But you have to install TestNG on your own from eclipse marketplace.

@Test is the same annotation used by JUnit as well as TestNG.

**Edit:**

For running TestNG tests in NetBeans IDE:

1)  http://wiki.netbeans.org/TestNG
2)  [how to work in selenium with testNG in Netbeans IDE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27921368/how-to-work-in-selenium-with-testng-in-netbeans-ide)

Comment: its already referenced, im not using eclipse, im using netbeans

Comment: have you installed TestNG plugin for Netbeans: http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/38973/testng-plugin

Comment: you have created TestNG xml for running tests?

Comment: I have been installed it, but I dont know how to create Testng XML.